# Change date format in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to change the format of the date from dd-mon-yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy, but it needs to be able to retain the date property when exported to an Excel spreadsheet. The to_char function changes it to text which then I have to manually change the field type back to date in order to be able to sort by date rather than alphabetically.

Comment: Try `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy'` or, if a column is not of date but timestamp datatype - `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy'`

Comment: Import the value into Excel as a date.  Then set the column format in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what datatype you are using (DATE or TIMESTAMP). Try to change the NLS parameter accordingly:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
```